# typoscript variable in plugin settings?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I am using a custom plugin and I need to add the page title as one of the plugin's settings variables:

```
plugin.tx_fsearch {
  settings {
    resultsPath = search-results/brand/{field:title}/make/{field:title}
    resultsPath.insertData = 1
  }
}
```

However this is outputting the word 'Array' instead of the path I need. 
Does anyone know how I might be able to make this work?

Comment: at least you need to use colons `{field:title}` instead of dots `{field.title}` for accessing fields in TS.

Answer (score 4):

There is no stdWrap available for settings in extbase extensions, no matter if using TEXT cObj or insertData!

As a workaround, you can fix that yourself by doing something like EXT:news does here https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/Controller/NewsController.php#L495

```
public function injectConfigurationManager(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface $configurationManager
) {
    $this->configurationManager = $configurationManager;
        $typoScriptService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\TypoScriptService::class);
        $typoScriptArray = $typoScriptService->convertPlainArrayToTypoScriptArray($originalSettings);
        $stdWrapProperties = GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $originalSettings['useStdWrap'], true);
        foreach ($stdWrapProperties as $key) {
            if (is_array($typoScriptArray[$key . '.'])) {
                $originalSettings[$key] = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->stdWrap(
                    $originalSettings[$key],
                    $typoScriptArray[$key . '.']
                );
            }
        }
    }
    $this->settings = $originalSettings;
}
```

Or you skip the TS part and call the stdWrap directly in your controller.

Comment: I didn't write the extension, so - bear with me - what do you mean by directly in my controller?

Comment: Sorry thought that this is your extension. if it is not, you can  XCLASS the controller to extend it but that is a different task

Answer (score -2):

Try TEXT object

```
plugin.tx_fsearch {
  settings {
    resultsPath = TEXT
    resultsPath.value = search-results/brand/{field.title}/make/{field.title}
  }
}
```

Comment: Same result "Array"

Comment: Do you want to fetch resultsPath in FLUID or in your controller?

Comment: as explained in my answer, no stdWrap is available while resolving settings